# scrolling in jquery doesn’t work with a div class that has vh height

Tags: jquery, html

I am encountering some issues with scrolling when a button is clicked to move to the next verbiage. The content is wrapped around a class: `<div class=“content”>` and it has a height of 60 vh. i’m trying to have it scroll within that height. I created a codepen example of the problem: 
 https://codepen.io/dude12go8/pen/PoYbdXd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scroll the content area not the window.

```
$('.content').animate({
    scrollTop: position
}, 100);
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/WebNesting/pen/QWLdbje

Comment: thank you so much. i was able to get it to work on my end. i made some adjustments to the offset variable at the top, but works perfectly